# Remove document and update database

Tags: php, javascript, sqlite

I have 2 files that assist me in removing the document and updating the database. 
My first file consists of 1 form with a remove button and a javascript function called remove(). Second php page would be removing the file which it does not return any results.

Code for Remove.php (Upon calling out remove() function):

```
$Doc=$_GET['Doc']; //Value get from remove() function
$ID= intval($_POST['ID']);
$FirstReport= $_POST['FirstReport'];
$SecReport = $_POST['SecReport'];

$FirstReportPath= $_POST['FirstReportPath'];
$SecReportPath = $_POST['SecReportPath '];

$DB = new PDO('sqlite:/database/Student.db');
//If i click remove firstreport button, i'll check it to see if it's the same
if(($Doc) == ($FirstReport))
{
   $result= $DB->query("Update Student set FirstReport='No' WHERE ID=".$ID);    
//This unlink should remove the document file from the path.
    unlink($FirstReportPath);
echo "success";
 }
 else
 {
    //same code repeated as if statement
 }
```

Javascript function

```
 function RemoveDoc(Doc)
 {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET","functions/Resubmit.php?Doc="+Doc,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 document.getElementById("RemoveMsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 return false;
 }
```

I did try to alert(Doc) out and the document name does show but on the second remove.php, it does not run any of the coding. Tried "GET"/"POST" also the same results. Kindly advise.

Comment: Please note that your PHP code as-is will allow someone to remove any arbitrary file on your server. Don't forget to validate your input.

Comment: i can move files into that folder. But i cant unlink it now.

Comment: did you output firstreport and firstreportpath and made sure they are of same case, same length , same chars including spaces?  use var_dump and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send the values ad post to access from $_POST superglobal. Just modify the Javascript code

```
function RemoveDoc(Doc,FirstReport,SecReport,FirstReportPath,SecReportPath)
{
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("POST","functions/Resubmit.php",true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      document.getElementById("RemoveMsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 xmlhttp.send("Doc="+Doc+"&FirstReport="+FirstReport+"&SecReport="+SecReport);
 //do for others also in the same way
 return false;
}
```

Comment: In this case, how I call out on the different buttons? as now is RemoveDoc(this.name).. which is RemoveDoc(this.doc). How i add in FirstReport in for the different buttons?

Comment: use custom tags for each buttons then try RemoveDoc(this.name,this.getAttribute("FirstReport"),.....etc)

Comment: Its in HTML not php  <button FirstReport="sample" name="sample_doc" ...etc>

Comment: like <input type ="Hidden" name="No" value= $No> How can i implement the function in here when it's hidden?

Comment: Tell me one thing what launches your RemoveDoc function?

Comment: to remove the document from the server? calls out the second php. So i need this values to check.

Comment: I mean there has to be a button or somethin which triggers it. If that  is the case add custom tags to the button itself

Comment: Please submit the HTML form so we can have a clear picture of what your asking.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your sending a post request, but sending your document name in the url, a $GET variable.

either switch to a get request:

```
function RemoveDoc(Doc)
 {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET","functions/Resubmit.php?Doc="+Doc,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 document.getElementById("RemoveMsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 return false;
 }
```

or send the document name as a post parameter:

```
function RemoveDoc(Doc)
 {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("POST","functions/Resubmit.php",true);
 xmlhttp.send("Doc="+Doc);
 document.getElementById("RemoveMsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 return false;
 }
```

Also, your not waiting for a response from the server.

```
function RemoveDoc(Doc)
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","functions/Resubmit.php",true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("RemoveMsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
 xmlhttp.send('Doc='+Doc);
return false;
}
```

Comment: You need to wait for the server response before trying to use it

Comment: Hi, I did try my all ways to call out my javascript function. I did try to alert(Doc). It did call out my correct Doc needed. But to the Resubmit.php, it doesnt call out...

Comment: Also, how are you posting the other parameters to the page? because they're not in the xmlHTTPRequest.

Comment: I thought by $_POST it will pass the variables to the resubmit.php ? I did the same for others and it works...